# Is there a method for translating markdown formatted text?

Tags: documentation, markdown, language-translation

I'm working on a project with a sizable amount of markdown formatted text that I would like to make available in different languages.

**Has anyone developed a process for producing and managing markdown content in multiple languages?**

Currently, our documentation is written in markdown. This documentation is then converted to HTML at build time and displayed within a custom built UI.

Obviously we can create a bunch of separate directories for each page, but I was hopeful that there might be some lessons learned from others that could make the organization and management of this content easier.

Comment: Do you have access to the raw html?  It would probably be easier to translate, then convert to markdown rather than the other way around.

Comment: We have a collection of developers who are writing their documentation in markdown.  This documentation is currently converted to HTML at build time and displayed within a UI that we built.  Obviously we can create a bunch of separate directories for each page, but I was hopeful that there might be some lessons learned from others that could make the organization and management of this content easier.

Comment: One non trivial solution if you are planning to do this in a long term would be to generate your markdown by applying an XSLT on your content XML i.e. apply your XSLT on you English XML => your English markdown, apply same XSLT on you Spanish XML => your Spanish markdown. Non trivial because the initial setup part is going to be tough.

Comment: I've created one that works with Markdown and HTML, based on the existing https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans library

Answer (score 3):

Someone created a CLI for *producing* translations with Google translate. Its on github here: [translate-markdown](https://github.com/rhysd/translate-markdown)

Comment: it does nothing

Comment: you need to pipe input into it

Answer (score 2):

I've created a set of tools to translate Markdown using `.po` files. It's capable of translate HTML produced from Markdown also. [Check it here](https://github.com/mondeja/mdpo).

Answer (score 1):

Hi GT4T can perfectly translate markdown files --- all formats kept, and codes will be kept intact as untranslatable.

And you can use any of the 30 automatic translation engines worldwide.

Download here https://gt4t.net/

Disclaimer: I am the developer

Comment: 2024 - works great - translated `.md` file swiftly and without errors

Comment: Thanks for confirming Boris. Feel free to contact me anytime.